# Quick find next finds all Sublime text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm using Sublime text 3, build 3126.
When I select a variable with `quick add next` it is selecting all instances of the word, regardless of variable or string.

Is this a bug, or my settings just off?

Srom my default settings:

```
// Highlights other occurrences of the currently selected text
"match_selection": true,
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Edit based on comment:**

Check to refactor: https://github.com/s-a/sublime-text-refactor

You can also do **cmd + click** (**ctrl + click** on windows) and select the variable manually, not ideal but may work on a moderate amount of code.

**Original Answer:**

That is how it works, it doesn't filter by type of data, simply by text content.

See below:

[image]

match_selection settings the same:

```
// Highlights other occurrences of the currently selected text
"match_selection": true,
```

Comment: How do I refactor a variable then?